# Printing an envelope from a web page

Tags: html, css, printing

Is there a way to specify the media type / page size to be used when the user prints a web page?  Also, can I lay out text so it will be printed at specific positions?

For example, I’d like to render an address on a web page that the user can then print on a letter-size envelope.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

By ***media type***, I meant the type of print media, such as *letter-size*, *legal-size*, *#10 envelope*, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the bottom line is best use a PDF. Sadly, Browsers suck very much at printing.

> Is there a way to specify the media type / page size to be used when the user prints a web page?

You can specify a CSS style sheet to apply only to printing using `media="print"`. As to the page size, there is no reliable way of specifying that. You will have to rely on the user to do this for you.

Also, you will have to rely on the user to remove the header and footer that most browsers add to the printed result.

> Also, can I lay out text so it will be printed at specific positions?

In theory, yes. You can use physical unit values `cm` or `in` to position elements on the page. I'm not sure whether these work with 100% reliability though, because printer specific margins may change the result - you'd have to test.

Comment: Errm... Yes, of course there is a media type for print?! `<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />` Or maybe the poster meant media type as in Glossy Paper / Normal paper... then you are correct of course.

Comment: @moontear I understood this in respect to the actual printed page, but I'll change that, good point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using CSS for different mediatypes, though I don't know if this will give you the precise control you're asking for.